# Skaffold and Gitlab image repositories

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, skaffold

This is my Skaffold config.

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta19
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: my-api
build:
  local:
    useDockerCLI: true
  artifacts:
    - image: registry.gitlab.com/lodiee/my-api
      docker:
        buildArgs:
          DATABASE_HOST: '{{.DATABASE_HOST}}'
deploy:
  helm:
    releases:
      - name: my-api
        artifactOverrides:
          image: registry.gitlab.com/lodiee/my-api
        imageStrategy:
          helm: {}
        remoteChart: bitnami/node
        setValueTemplates:
          image.tag: '{{.DIGEST_HEX}}'
        setValues:
          image.repository: registry.gitlab.com/lodiee/my-api
```

When I run Skaffold dev, everything works fine until I see an ImagePullBackoff error in pod logs. Here is a partial output of the log:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  102s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/my-api-node-55cf68d989-7vltw to kind-control-plane
  Normal   BackOff    21s (x5 over 99s)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "docker.io/registry.gitlab.com/lodiee/my-api:60ef7d4a463e269de9e176afbdd2362fd50870e494ff7a8abf25ece16c0d100c"
  Warning  Failed     21s (x5 over 99s)  kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    6s (x4 over 101s)  kubelet            Pulling image "docker.io/registry.gitlab.com/lodiee/my-api:60ef7d4a463e269de9e176afbdd2362fd50870e494ff7a8abf25ece16c0d100c"
  Warning  Failed     4s (x4 over 100s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "docker.io/registry.gitlab.com/lodiee/my-api:60ef7d4a463e269de9e176afbdd2362fd50870e494ff7a8abf25ece16c0d100c": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/registry.gitlab.com/lodiee/my-api:60ef7d4a463e269de9e176afbdd2362fd50870e494ff7a8abf25ece16c0d100c": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/registry.gitlab.com/lodiee/my-api:60ef7d4a463e269de9e176afbdd2362fd50870e494ff7a8abf25ece16c0d100c": pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

As you can see from the output, kubernetes adds docker.io prefix in front of my image repo address and so it can't find the image at that address.

Is this the normal behavior? Also this is a local development setup and I use `skaffold dev` to launch it, why does k8s try to go to that address?

Thank you.

Comment: Something isn't right and I can't reproduce this locally.  Please check your `~/.skaffold/config` to see if there's a `default-repo` setting.  Otherwise please open a new issue on the Skaffold Github and include the output of running with the `-vdebug` flag to produce more output, being sure to redact any sensitive information. That should help show where and why this image ref is being rewritten.

Comment: are you using a Kind cluster by chance?  We've seen another user having issues with Kind where the image is being prefixed with `docker.io`.

Comment: @BriandeAlwis yes I was running on a KinD cluster.

Comment: Élodie, what version of KinD are you using?  Do you see the issue if you use an older release?